# Towards the "true" definition of JAVA_HOME 

Tags: java, java-home

As a Java developer who switches between *NIX systems (OS X, Ubuntu, ...), although I can always "get" my JDK up and running, it seems that there is no clear definition of JAVA_HOME in many packages which require JAVA_HOME to be set :

**For example**

- MAVEN  : "JAVA_HOME, refers to your JDK directory"
- HADOOP : "JAVA_HOME, which specifies the path to the Java 1.5.x installation"
- SUN :  "JAVA_HOME is the directory that contains the JRE"

**I thus have 2 questions regarding this matter** (any insights would be welcome, also, but concretely, I have these two questions) :

1) Does mac os X java installation copy the target from the "JavaVM.frameworks" directory into usr/bin ?

2) What is the "definition" of JAVA_HOME ?  Clearly, we cannot define JAVA_HOME as simply "the place where java is installed", because this definition is ambiguous, since java can exist both in a HOME location (i.e. in /System/Library/Fraemworks/.....) , or alternatively, it may also be directly in the /usr/bin directory ?

**MY THOUGHTS**

I believe that JAVA_HOME is ACTUALLY meant to refer to more than just a binary "java" program.  JAVA_HOME probably is meant to refer to the location of a set of java related directories AND binaries... But still, I am not really clear what this comprises, and wether or not this definition which I am proposing is precise enough to be useful.

Comment: It's exactly what all three of your examples say because all three of those examples specify the *exact same thing*. It's the top level directory of the JDK (which includes the JRE), or if you haven't installed that, the top level directory of the JRE installation.

Comment: are you sure ? I don't beleive that the JDK=JRE.  For example, consider an installation of JAVA which doesn't include the JDK (only the JRE) .....

Comment: The directory structures of the JDK and JRE are the same to facilitate this. That's why it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no "true" definition of `JAVA_HOME`. This variable is not used by the Java Runtime Environment, and has no specification as part of the Java platform.

It is merely a convention that is used by some applications that run on top of the Java platform. Since there's no standard, each application is free to make its own rules about the directory to which this variable should refer; you should read the application's documentation to find out what it needs.

That said, every application I've found that uses this variable will work if you set it to the top level directory of a JDK installation (not the JRE within the JDK, but the JDK itself). This directory should contain "bin" and "lib" subdirectories that contain the `java` executable and the runtime libraries, respectively.

Some applications will also work if you point it at a JRE, but if it needs development tools like `javac`, it will fail.

Usually, I specify `JAVA_HOME` on the command line when I run a tool than needs it, because I work with multiple versions of Java, like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_29 ant
```

Comment: plus-1 for the JAVA_HOME before program (ant).

Answer (score 2):

I would define it like the path such:

```
`JAVA_HOME\bin\java`
```

where the executable that will run your programs is.

The source root to look for all your `SDK JRE files and jars`.

Answer (score 2):

Sun's convention refers to java home as the jre root dir. This should be the more authoritative definition.

For dev tools like maven, they would mostly care about jdk dir. They should have called it "JDK home". Unfortunately many call it "java home" too, hence the confusion.

We can break the confusion by not using "java home"; instead, say "jre home" or "jdk home" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about what it is set to on different systems, but `JAVA_HOME` should be set to the root of the java installation. So if you have it installed to

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\`

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to that.

Similar to `JDK_HOME` if you see that in writing.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should point to the installation directory of the Java installation you want to use.

Comment: so, if I have java in /usr/bin/ WHILE ALSO having java installed in /System/Frameworks/....  is JAVA_HOME=/usr/ ?  or should it point to the framework VM.?

Comment: Neither. You point it to the JDK or JRE installation directory. This really isn't complicated. `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink to the java binary located in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`