# Can't install Apache Maven following instructions

Tags: apache, maven

I'm a complete novice at using the terminal. What I've trying to do is install Apache Maven, following these instructions at this website:

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

I've included the instructions below, a screenshot showing the folder I've unzipped, and the commands I entered into the terminal.

But it doesn't seem to be working

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a java binary under $JAVA_HOME/bin ?  Did you install java at all ? Probably not such a vintage version anyway.  You should install java and see where it lives (which java) and change your JAVA_HOME

Comment: Assuming that you are installing on a Mac the JAVA_HOME location is defintivley wrong. Should be something `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home` for JAVA 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically **JAVA_HOME** is not installed in */usr/java* by default like on some other UNIX/Linux such as Fedora for example.

On OSX, your Java installation is typically inside a sub-folder of */System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*.

Try setting **JAVA_HOME** like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Double-check your **JAVA_HOME** location

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thank you! What does setting Java_Home mean?

Comment: You may want to look at a similar SO question for JAVA_HOME meaning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173120/towards-the-true-definition-of-java-home. It's just a convention used by Applications to locate Java and sometimes the tools.jar file location.

Comment: If you were to use Java 1.7, please following @khmarbaise instructions. I believe that if you run java -version, it will report 1.6.x.

Comment: Yup Java version: 1.6.0_45, which I think is what came pre-installed in this mac.