# Ubuntu: where is java_home environment variable stored

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, java-home

I have installed java by these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

If I understood properly these commands above garantee that java will update automatically.
I have been using Eclipse, STS and Tomcat successfully, then I believe that java is properly installed with its environments.

But I want to know where is the java_home environment. I tried:

1. `gedit /etc/environment` I found:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
   GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle/gradle-1.6"
   ```
2. `whereis java` (I believe that this is just a file find)

   ```
   java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
   ```
3. `gedit ~/.pam_environment` But it is completely empty
4. `gedit ~/.bashrc` and after `gedit .profile` (I believe that this is just script files that run while starting linux). But I didn't find any string with "java".
5. `printenv JAVA_HOME` (I believe that this only prints variables set by export and it is valid only for the exact session you set) But nothing has printed.

I am new to Linux. Could someone help me find where is the java environment in my system and please adjust any wrong believes I wrote before?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not part of the JRE (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8173260/3474)). It's just a convention used by some Java-based tools. You should not expect any installation to set it for you.

Comment: By the by, the `GRADLE_HOME` variable needs to be set before you can include it in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
grep JAVA_HOME /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile.d/* /etc/profile
```

In my case after installing java from webupd8team ppa in Ubuntu 18.04 the scripts with setting and exporting JAVA_HOME variable are located in

```
/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh:setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 4):

When installing java with the webupd8team ppa you will need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable yourself. You can do this in many ways. How I did it is as follows:

1. Run the `sudo update-alternatives --config java` command to get the list of java installations. It will also display the location of the java executable. e.g. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`.
2. From the java installation that you use select the path up to `jre`. e.g. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`. This will become your JAVA_HOME path.
3. Then edit your ~/.bashrc file and add the following line:
   `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"`.
4. Either restart your terminal, or type `bash`.

This should set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an Ubuntu with Java right now, but I've done this in the past.
http://www.janosgyerik.com/installing-java-and-setting-java_home-in-ubuntu/

Edit `/etc/jvm`, add this line to the top of the list: `/path/to/your/jvm`, which in your case is probably: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` but you have to check, maybe `locate`java-7-oracle` might help.

Thanks to the above step, the `java` executable will find the right version of Java. You can confirm this by running the command:

```
java -version
```

However, setting `JAVA_HOME` is a different matter. These commands worked in my older version of Ubuntu to detect + set + confirm `JAVA_HOME`:

```
. /usr/share/java-common/java-common.sh
eval $(jvm_config)
export JAVA_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If the output looks good, then add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question.

Comment: Janos, I noted that /etc/jvm is empty in my Ubuntu but following your instructions about locate, I think I can make a question more specific: in Windows I must set java environment variable otherwise the Eclipse wouldn't run. Now, as my first work in linux, I just installed java but I didn't set any environment variable for java and Eclipse is running perfectly for my surprise. I guess that in linux for some reason setting environment variables is not necessary for Eclipse to work. I noted that there is a link

Comment: ...I noted that in /usr/bin there is a link to /etc/alternatives/java which in turn is also a link for /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java. Then I guess that in linux it is enough to put a link in /usr/bin which points to the binaries file. Am I right?

Comment: @user79885 Eclipse needs JAVA_HOME to know where to find Java it can use for compiling your projects. I guess this is easier to do in Linux, for example it's easy to detect if a `java` executable exists and track down its path and figure out the correct JAVA_HOME. This is just a guess, I don't know how it really does it.

Comment: @user79885 ...as per the links in `/usr/bin`, don't mess with them manually. Let the package manager set those things, or use the `update-alternatives` command.

Comment: @user79885, thank you. Do you know how do I set to be done automatically? For example, today the current version is 7.5. Imagine that tomorrow it is released 7.6. Will this be download and installed automatically similar to Windows, or do I have to run commands again? If I should do by myself, which from these 4 lines should I run? Maybe, only the last one?
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle

Comment: @user79885 you can get automatic upgrades using these two commands: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` These upgrade your entire system though, not only Java. If you want to upgrade *only* Java, then the second command is `sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME`. I cannot confirm the package name because I don't have an ubuntu right now... I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is at /etc/bash.bashrc
You are right, using the ppa repository guarantees that Java will update automatically when you update your system.