# Get java.home out of the JVM without writing Java code to print it

Tags: java, jvm

According to several posts (e.g. [Towards the "true" definition of JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173120/towards-the-true-definition-of-java-home/8173260#8173260) ), and searching through some of the documentation available, `JAVA_HOME` has nothing to do with the JVM itself and is not used by it.

Yet some software requires it to be set, likely to exactly the value that the system property `java.home` has. Under the assumption that `java` is in the `PATH`, is there anyway to squeeze this system property out of the JVM that is portable between Windows/Unix/Mac --- except writing and compiling this handful lines of code to sysout the property?

I am really hoping for some less known command line option or other cute trick. Assuming a jdk (rather than jre) would be fine. How about some self-referential stuff with `jps`, `jstack`, `jidunnothatitevenexits`?

`jshell` in Java-9 makes it easy. But I need a solution for Java-8, maybe even -7. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nashorn JavaScript engine is available in Java 8:

```
$ jjs
jjs> print(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"))
```

That's JavaScript, not Java code.  ;-)

Works in Java 9, too.  Sadly, not in Java 7.

---

**Update**

I think this works in 7, 8, and 9.

```
jrunscript -e 'print(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"))'
```

---

**Update 2**

Reversing the roles of the quote characters is allowed ...

```
jrunscript -e "print(java.lang.System.getProperty('java.home'))"
```

... and apparently necessary for Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Confirmed.  The `jrunscript` approach works with Java 7.

Comment: Hmm, I was about to accept this, because it really looks cool --- except I cannot get it to work on Windows:
 `& "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\jrunscript.EXE"  -e 'print(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"))'`, prints `null` although this is really hard to believe. I must be doing something stupid. :-(

Comment: Ooooh no, swapping the role of `'` and `"` in the powershell call gets it to work. (Need to file another question about what is going on in powershell there.:-)

Comment: Not a problem.  `’java.home’` is valid as a string in JavaScript, so swapping the quote characters is fine.  I’ll add that to my answer, for completeness.

Comment: @Harald PowerShell is treating `print(java.lang.System.print("java.home"))` as `print(java.lang.System.print(java.home))`. (Figured that out by changing it to `print(java.lang.System.print("java.home", "default"))`.)  So, why does it print `null`?  Executing `print(java.home)` will produce `[JavaPackage java.home]`, and of course there is no property with that key, so `null` is returned.  Thank-you PowerShell.  (sigh.)